# Session timeout in Web appicaltion

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, session, iis

In an aspx webform application .
I have set `session.timeout` 10 mins .

But the webpage sends automatic ajax request (using javascript timer) in every 5 mins

So session timeout do not occur even though the user remains idle more than 10 mins .

User session should expire after 10 mins if user remains idle , do not consider automatic ajax requests . Is there a way to check last manual user interaction time ?

Any solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple script using JQuery that handles mousemove and keypress events. If the time expires, the page reload.

**Client side**:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var idleTime = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
        var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

        //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
        $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
        $(this).keypress(function (e) {
            idleTime = 0;
        });
    });

    function timerIncrement() {
        idleTime = idleTime + 1;
        if (idleTime > 9) { // 10 minutes
           // Here You'd have to have a little ajax call to server to set all session variable value as null.
        }
    }
    function setAllSessionNull(){
//make ajax call to server to set all session variable value as null.
// redirect to login page
}
    </script>
```

**c# code to get all session & set null**:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Session.Count; i++)
            {
                Session.Remove(Session.Keys[i]); 

            }
```